# "Application ... not registered" with React Native app on AWS Mobile Hub

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, aws-mobilehub

I'm trying to learn and understand how AWS Mobile Hub works.
Based on  I'm trying to create a React Native app from scratch and connect to a AWS Mobile Hub.

- I followed the steps in the [AWS Mobile React Native Starter # Use features in your app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-react-native-starter#use-features-in-your-app) to create a React Native app from scratch.
- Setup a new project in AWS Mobile Hub.

  - Used `awsmobile init <ID>` to setup the react project for AWS Mobile Hub.
  - Enabled User Sign-in on AWS Mobile Hub project.
- Setup Authentication in the React Native project.
  (ps. there is an error in the guidelines because 'Amplify' import is missing)
- Run the app with `npm run ios`

No matter what I do, I alway get a 'Application ... has not been registered' error.

The example backend from 'AWS Mobile React Native Starter' does work.
I have tried to compare both AWS Mobile Projects, but cannot find what causes the 'Application ... has not been registered' error.

I want to understand this AWS Mobile Hub thing and want to be able to setup projects myself and know how to integrate it into apps.
Any help to solve this error is **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the problem.
First I thought it was because `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` were missing, but then saw those are not needed anymore.

Aparently, when doing an application from scratch, the created 'index.js' does not have the correct component name. Changing the wrong name in  `AppRegistry.registerComponent('wrongname', () => App);` to the correct application name, matching `aws_project_name` in `aws-exports.js`, fixed the issue.

The app now loads. Hurray!
Next problem: when signing in I get a 'No Userpool' message. Checked all config and Mobile Hub project, but the user pool seems correctly configured...

Update: also found the issue with 'No userpool'. When debugging the application, I noticed that the configuration received by `Amplify.configure` function was `undefined`. But I copied this code:

`import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import {awsmobile} from './aws-exports';`

from [this AWS React Native Starter App tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-react-native-starter#authentication-). But apparently it is not working.

Replacing that bit by this:

`import Amplify from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';`

from 
[AWS Documentation » AWS Mobile » Developer Guide » AWS Amplify Library for React Native » Get Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/react-native-getting-started.html)
. Now it suddenly works.

Thanks AWS! Took me couple of nights to find :-/

Comment: Wonderful. However Amplify from aws-amplify-react-native is deprecated. Here's my working solution:

```import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator, Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import awsmobile from './dist/aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
export class App extends React.Component {}
export default AppWithAuth = withAuthenticator(App);```

Comment: @ThomasHagström Thanks for you solution. Where did you see aws-amplify-react-native is deprecated? Just looked at the project and looks alive-and-kicking to me (https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify). Last commit was only 10 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that problem before when there is a version of aws-amplify installed under aws-amplify-react-native. That happens when the version of aws-amplify installed on the project is not the one that requires aws-amplify-react-native. I hope everything goes well with your app.